# Hibernate Composite key with database generated timestamp

Tags: hibernate

I'm having trouble saving an object with a composite primary key using Hibernate 3.3 and annotations.

My key consists of a user's unique ID and a database generate Timestamp.

How do I map this key using annotations? I've used some reverse engineering tools, but when I try to save the entity I run into problems.

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTIVITY_LOG", schema = "WEB")
public class ActivityLog implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private ActivityLogId id;
    private SearchAuditRecord searchAuditRecord;

    // Constructors

         .....

    // Property accessors
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "identifier", column = @Column(name = "IDENTIFIER", nullable = false, length = 11)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "createTimestamp", column = @Column(name = "CREATE_TIMESTAMP", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable = false, length = 26)) })
    public ActivityLogId getId() {
    return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(ActivityLogId id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    .....

}


@Embeddable
public class ActivityLogId implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private String identifier;
    private Date createTimestamp;

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
public ActivityLogId() {
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public ActivityLogId(String hrmisIdentifier, Date createTimestamp) {
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.createTimestamp = createTimestamp;
}

// Property accessors

    @Column(name = "IDENTIFIER", nullable = false, length = 11)
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return this.identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }


    @Column(name = "CREATE_TIMESTAMP",insertable= false, updatable= false,  nullable = false, length = 26)
    public Date getCreateTimestamp() {
        return this.createTimestamp;
    }

    public void setCreateTimestamp(Timestamp createTimestamp) {
        this.createTimestamp = createTimestamp;
    }

}
```

I figure I need to tell Hibernate that ActivityLogID.createTimestamp is being created by the Database... but I'm not sure how.

As it stand right now, when I try to save theses objects I get:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: 
could not insert: [ca.gc.rcmp.persistence.ActivityLog]........ 
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fo: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC= , DRIVER=3.57.82
```

Which is telling me I can't put a null into a Not-null column. CreateTimestamp is the only field in my entity that is null.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **["Generated properties"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-generated)** section of the hibernate documentation. Annotate with ALWAYS or INSERT depending on your use case

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
```